# Execute multiple macros in one line in cmd.exe

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I can define and run a macro like this:

```
C:\Users\kvu787>doskey ew=echo world

C:\Users\kvu787>ew
world
```

However, cmd.exe fails to recognize the macro if it's not the first command in an `&` chain:

```
C:\Users\kvu787>echo hello & ew
hello
'ew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I run a mix of commands and doskey macros in a single line?

Comment: It's not cmd.exe failing - it doesn't know anything about macros. It's the way doskey intercepts commands only at the begin of an input line and presents the macro to cmd.exe.

Comment: @LotPings, in practice this isn't implemented by doskey.exe in NT based systems. doskey.exe sets a console alias via [`AddConsoleAlias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/addconsolealias). The console host (conhost.exe) is what substitutes aliases that match at the beginning of the current line, depending on the `ExeName` that's reading from the console. doskey.exe supports the `/exename` target for an alias, which defaults to cmd.exe.

Comment: cmd.exe has no macro facility. Console aliases set via doskey.exe are not commands that can be used arbitrarily on the command line, and obviously they're not available at all as commands in a batch script. Use batch scripts instead of doskey.exe.

Comment: @eryksun So in pratice, you are saying the same - with a much better detailed technical explanation ;-)

Comment: @LotPings, saying "doskey intercepts commands" belies what happens. It is technically wrong. With your description, one would presume that doskey.exe injects a DLL in the calling process or a child process that hooks APIs such as `ReadFile` and `ReadConsoleW`. That's not beyond reason, as it's what ANSICON and ConEmu do to implement their hacks into the console API, but it's not the case here. Console aliases are standard Windows functionality, in this case called from a command-line "doskey" utility, which is only superficially similar to the legacy DOS TSR of the same name.

Comment: What about using a batch file (like `ew.bat` containing `echo world`) rather than macros, and then to run it like `echo hello& call ew.bat`?